# Use of the dot in math-mode

Tags: math-mode

I was trying to typesset piecewise functions earlier and I had a problem typesseting only the left brace and not the right as it couldn't accept only `\left\{`. After that I tried adding `\right` but there were still errors. Until I found out this piece of code in wikipedia showing a dot after `\right`. What is the use of this dot?

```
\[f(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    x^2 & : x < 0\\
    x^3 & : x \ge 0
  \end{array}
\right.
\]
```

Comment: Simply expressed: The dot fakes a closing 'bracket' when you opened a left one. Normally, LaTeX expects a right 'bracket', omitting it will lead to errors. The dot's job is to prevent this

Comment: `.` has delimiter code 0 which means that it is a legal delimiter that can go after `\left` or `\right` it causes the horizontal space `\nulldelimiterspace` to be added and allows `\left` `\right` pairs to match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `\left\{` should always be matched with a `\right\}` in the same line. This will put the opening and closing braces both. In case if you want only the opening brace (`\left\{`) then you need to match it with an invisible `\right.` The `.` is for invisible pair. Same thing is true for `\left.` if you want only the closing pair.